# Devexpress silverlight grid header checkbox column

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, grid, devexpress

Is it possible to select or deselect the `check box` ( `silverlight devexpress grid` check box ) based on Grid header `checkbox` column , using client side events or server side events.

Sample Code :

```
        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView NavigationStyle="Cell" VerticalContentAlignment="Top"   AllowColumnFiltering="True" AllowFilterEditor="True" ShowTotalSummary="True" Foreground="Black" ShowGroupPanel="False" AllowEditing="False" >
            </dxg:TableView>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="EID" Fixed="Left" Width="70"  VerticalAlignment="Top" AllowFocus="False" FilterPopupMode="CheckedList"></dxg:GridColumn>
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="EN" Header="Name" Width="180" AutoFilterCondition="Contains" Fixed="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" AllowFocus="False" FilterPopupMode="CheckedList" />
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="DOJ" Header="Date Of Joining" Width="110" AllowFocus="False" FilterPopupMode="CheckedList" />
            <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="CEX" Width="170" Visible="True" AutoFilterCondition="Like" AllowFocus="False" FilterPopupMode="CheckedList" />
    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="CheckBoxColumn" Width="170" Visible="True" AutoFilterCondition="Like" AllowFocus="False" FilterPopupMode="CheckedList" />
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridControl.GroupSummary>
            <dxg:GridSummaryItem SummaryType="Count" />
        </dxg:GridControl.GroupSummary>
        <dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
            <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="EID" ShowInColumn="EN" SummaryType="Count"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
    </dxg:GridControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the cell template in order to achieve what you want.
It will be something like this:

```
        <dxg:GridColumn VisibleIndex="38" Header="h1" FieldName="h1" Name="h1">
            <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <dxe:CheckEdit IsChecked="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    </dxe:CheckEdit>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        </dxg:GridColumn>
```

After creating the new template you can access your Column and load its content in order to modify the element within it:

```
var checkBox = MyGrid.Columns["h1"].CellTemplate.LoadContent() as DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.CheckEdit
```

Then

```
checkBox.IsChecked = true
```

Hope it helps!